# Cannot use string offset as an array in addressfield_widget_process()

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am trying to figure out a problem in the drupal module used - addressfield. 
On `addressfield.module` I am getting a warning:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in addressfield_widget_process()

and then the error:

> Cannot use string offset as an array in addressfield_widget_process().

This is happening only when I choose Country South Africa(ZA), for php 7.1.
Somehow the array is string?!

I have tried some solutions from this error but I can not understand why is happening in this case or how to fix it.

```
function addressfield_widget_process($element) 
{
    foreach (element_children($element) as $key) {
        $element[$key]['#parents'] = $element['#parents'];
        $element[$key]['#parents'][count($element[$key]['#parents']) - 1] = $key;
    }
  }

  return $element;
}
```

Error is coming for this line:

```
$element[$key]['#parents'][count($element[$key]['#parents']) - 1] = $key;
```

Comment: That sounds like the underlying data is simply wrong somehow for South Africa. Can you do a var_dump of `element_children($element)` in that method, and check if the data for South Africa looks significantly different from that for any country that does not cause this error?

Comment: I have done that. Apparently for the South Africa another field is added which is "locality" which you can type your city. Thats the only difference. I read somewhere that says  "Because PHP is a very forgiving programming language, I'd guess."